# How to remove a child li element by text value search key?

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, contains

I have passed down a text value that matches the text of a li tab element in a list.

I then need to remove any tabs on the page matching that search text value. So for example I pass down `"Chart1"` to the `ClearGraph` method it should remove any tabs matching with that text value in the list.

So this is what I tried in the method, passed down the chart-text value and called `.contains()` then `.remove()`:

```
    function clearGraph(chart_text)
    {
        //Remove the chart tab by the text value
        $('#chartTabs li:contains('+ chart_text + ")'").remove();

    }
```

But I get a console error when calling the method, `jquery-2.2.2.js:1468 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #chartTabs li:contains( Chart 1)'`.

**Question:**
How can you remove a child `li` element by text value search key?

The markup and associated ClearGraph method is defined as follows:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="chartTabs">
        @* dynamically create the tab elements in d3 js *@
    </ul>


    function clearGraph(chart_text)
    {
        //Remove the chart tab by the text value
        $('#chartTabs li:contains('+ chart_text + ")'").remove();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `'`

```js
$('button').click(function()
{
  var input = $('input').val();
  $("#chartTabs li:contains('" + input + "')").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="chartTabs">
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
</ul>
<input type="text"/>
<button type="button">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your code. Extra quote in end is breaking the selector. You need to use:

```
$('#chartTabs li:contains('+ chart_text + ')').remove();
```